# How to use pad left method in C++/CLI

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I'm trying to pad '0' to the left of an `unsigned int` in C++ using CLI.
This is what I tried,

```
unsigned int pSz = 65; // This pSz value can range from 0 to 9999
String^ sizeOfPkt(pSz.ToString());
sizeOfPkt->PadLeft(4, L'0');
```

If the value of `pSz` is 65 then I'm expecting 0065 to be the `sizeOfPkt` value.
If the value of `pSz` is 350 then I'm expecting 0350 to be the `sizeOfPkt` value.

Can someone pls. suggest any ways to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get a new string. The function in the string class usually never modify an existing string. They create a new one and return the result.

```
unsigned int pSz = 65; 
String^ sizeOfPkt(pSz.ToString()->PadLeft(4,L'0'));
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot @xMRi